# Query for a row where the same value is shared across columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

- Employees `Alias`, `Manager`, `Auditor`, `Activator`

The `Alias` is unique.

Scenario: an employee needs to get his/her account reactivated. To do this they must go through a process of verification.

The table will then place an alias number into each column ( manager, auditor, activator) of whomever does the request. By rule employee cannot use his or herself to activate their own account.

How can i write a query to list all rows and columns displaying an employee having their alias showing up under **manager and auditor, or manager and activator**? ( in other words they are breaking the rules and verifying themselves)

Comment: Edit the question with sample data and expected output

Comment: Removing noise such as `employees from the company` helps readability. Grouping your text into paragraphs may also help at that. Sql and Mysql are two different thing, I've assumed you meant MySQL so I removed the `SQL` tag, please edit the question with the correct tag (one of them) should I have been wrong. And as commented by NoDisplayName, please include sample data in your question!

Comment: Sorry i'm completely new to the website and getting use to rules, protocol, and way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Is the rule you're looking for that the alias needs to be different to the manager, auditor and activator values?

If so, could you try a query like this?

```
SELECT alias, manager, auditor, activator
FROM employees
WHERE alias = manager
OR alias = auditor
OR alias = activator;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your statement

> alias showing up under manager and auditor, or manager and activator

```
SELECT alias, manager, auditor, activator
FROM Employees
WHERE (manager = alias AND auditor = alias) OR (manager = alias AND activator = alias)
```

Comment: THIS answered my question. Thank you so much for bearing with my poorly constructed question! TY!

Comment: please don't forget to mark my answer as the answer.